# Minimum area between target linestring and a collection of other linestrings?

Tags: r, geospatial, distance, spatial, area

I have a problem wherein I want to extract two scores for a set of target linestrings, T: 1. The Euclidean distances of T, 2. the average "closeness" to a second set of static linestring features, S.

At current, I am conducting a set of distance samples in SF using ST_NEAREST_POINTS between sample points along T and all features in S. This provides a set of shortest linestrings between the points and features which I can measure with ST_LENGTH and average to produce an approximate measure of "closeness".

Unfortunately, this is quite slow as T and S are relatively large. I was thinking a quicker way than a tonne of point samples would be to find the area between T and S, but I'm having some trouble figuring out how to implement that. For example, I could cast the start and end points of T through ST_NEAREST_POINTS to find the boundaries of a POLYGON which could then pass through ST_AREA, but the problem arises when the closest feature in S to T changes along the length of T. I've included a picture illustrating this problem with the (rough) solution, where the red edge is a member of T, black edges represent S, and the grey areas represent the minimal areas between T and S, which could be summed as a more complete second score.

Anyone know of a good way of calculating this? Thanks in advance.

[image: Diagram of problem with potential solution]

Example code for generating static and target linestrings below.

```
static_lines = matrix(runif(20, -100, 100),ncol = 2) |> 
  as.data.frame() |> 
  sf::st_as_sf(coords = c("V1", "V2"))

#random walks
static_lines = 
  do.call(c, apply(static_lines, MARGIN = 1, FUN = function(x){
  for(i in 1:20){
    if(i == 1){line = x |> sf::st_as_sfc()}
    last = line |> sf::st_cast("POINT")
    last = last[length(last)]
    line = c(line |> sf::st_cast("POINT"), 
             sf::st_sample(sf::st_difference(sf::st_buffer(last, 20),sf::st_buffer(line,5)), 1)) |> 
      sf::st_combine() |> 
      sf::st_cast("LINESTRING")
  }
  line
}))

target_lines = matrix(runif(20, -100, 100),ncol = 2) |> 
as.data.frame() |> 
sf::st_as_sf(coords = c("V1", "V2"))

#single step random-walk
target_lines = 
  do.call(c, apply(target_lines, MARGIN = 1, FUN = function(x){
      line = x |> sf::st_as_sfc()
      last = line |> sf::st_cast("POINT")
      last = last[length(last)]
      line = c(line |> sf::st_cast("POINT"), 
               sf::st_sample(sf::st_difference(sf::st_buffer(last, 20),sf::st_buffer(line,5)), 1)) |> 
        sf::st_combine() |> 
        sf::st_cast("LINESTRING")
    line
  }))

#plot
plot(static_lines)
plot(target_lines, add = T, col = "red", lwd = 3)
```

Comment: Could you provide a small reproducible dataset? Would a distance raster of S and raster extraction along T features work for your application or it would not be practical because of area coverage and resolution requirements?

Comment: Added dataset generator script above :)

Comment: Also, regarding the raster, I would prefer not to use discrete/apportioned solutions to this problem. The closer I can get to a continuous solution the better.